# Gravatar photo not updating. It has been a couple of months

Tags: support, gravatar

I was originaly using the Dilbert dog image, before I knew that Dilbert was a thing, for my Gravatar.

I have since discovered that Dilbert is a well established (and really good) cartoon strip. So, **a couple of months ago** I updated my Gravatar image to a picture of myself.

It still hasn't updated on SE, and **I don't think I should have to change my email address** just to update a picture so please don't close this as an exact duplicate as in all of the supposedly duplicate instances of this question, the answers all suggest either to wait longer (it's been a few months) or change my email address (nope).

Comment: Does your email address have an MD5 hash value of `27f23b2fc14929eb280dd650e52f88a5`?  If not, then you're changing the wrong gravatar...

Comment: @Charles Can you elaborate?

Comment: @JMK, the gravatar service bases their identity-based images on an MD5 hash of the email address associated with the user.  If you have updated your gravatar on their site, but you are not seeing the change here, then the email address you used on gravatar's site isn't the email address SO is using to pull the icon.  You need to either update the image on gravatar's site for the correct email address, or update SO to use the email address that gravatar thinks you should have.

Comment: For what it's worth I'm currently seeing the Gravatar default geometric icon instead of a dog *or* a picture.

Comment: @MarkRansom well so am I now, I have been seeing the geometric icon when signed in as myself for a while, but from my colleagues account, or when not logged in I have been seeing the dog (checked earlier today) but now it is indeed showing the geometric account from all three.

Comment: @Charles I didn't know about the hash value, my primary email address is the same as my gravatar email address, but was added second (before I added the cartoon dog) so that makes sense! I think you all need to give me a -1 for wasting your time, and then we can close this question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your profile has the default MD5-of-your-email geometric picture, meaning that Gravatar.com has *no* picture associated with the email address used on StackOverflow.com.

Verify your email address on SO and ensure that Gravatar.com has an image associated with that specific address.

Comment: That was it, I signed up for SO with email address A, added my Gravatar and signed up for Gravatar with email address A, changed both email addresses to email address B, and then tried to update my Gravatar, but the image itself had an MD5 of email address A so it didn't work!